# How to detect if the user is still trying to scroll when the bottom of the page is already reached?

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the bottom of the page I have three `<div>`s, each representing a step.
As they become completely visible when the user scrolls all the way to the bottom of the page, I want to advance a CSS animation whenever the user tries to further scroll(beyond the bottom of the page),and highlight a different one of the three steps as the user scrolls. The animation will consist of a rocket ship icon that will move from the left to the right of  as the user keeps trying to scroll, and the current step being highlighted with a lighter color- functioning as a progress bar, indicating the current step.

**However, the dilemma is that I can't seem to detect scroll events after the scroll bar has already reached the bottom of the page. How do I do I get an event handler to pick up these scroll attempts?**

Here's the event handler I have set up that isn't called after the bottom of the page has already been reached:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        console.log("You're at the bottom of the page");
    }
};
```

Here's the three steps I want to advance through:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`onwheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) event:

```
window.onwheel = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        console.log("You're at the bottom of the page");
    }
};
```